# Set bar graph last column as default blue color. Note 'Data is called through API'

Tags: javascript, charts, bar-chart, google-visualization

[image: Bar Graph]

> 'My question is about changing the last column of a graph to blue. What I want to do is changing **18Dec Bar** to **blue color**. Thanks in advance'

```
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
var jsonData = $.ajax({
type: 'GET',
        url: "{{ url('/dateusersbarchartdata') }}/" + period,
        dataType: "json",
        global: false,
        async: false,
        success: function (jsondata) {

        }
}).responseText;
var array = $.parseJSON(jsonData);
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(array);
var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('container- 
user'));
var colors = ['#B0C4DE', '#1E90FF'];
var options = {
orientation: 'horizontal',
        backgroundColor: {fill: 'transparent'},
        chartArea: {'width': '100%', 'height': '80%'},

        series: {0: {color: '#B0C4DE'}},

        };
   chart.draw(data, options, {colors: colors});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a `'style'` [column role](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles).

this will allow you to change the color of individual bars.

in the data table, add an object for the column heading.

```
['x', 'y0', {role: 'style', type: 'string'}],  // <-- column role
```

then in the data rows, add the color for the bar.

```
['18Sep', 600, '#B0C4DE'],
['18Dec', 1500, '#1E90FF']  // <-- last bar
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x', 'y0', {role: 'style', type: 'string'}],
    ['17Jun', 1000, '#B0C4DE'],
    ['17Sep', 500, '#B0C4DE'],
    ['17Dec', 1000, '#B0C4DE'],
    ['18Mar', 750, '#B0C4DE'],
    ['18Jun', 1200, '#B0C4DE'],
    ['18Sep', 600, '#B0C4DE'],
    ['18Dec', 1500, '#1E90FF']
  ]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('container-user'));
  var options = {
    orientation: 'horizontal',
    backgroundColor: {fill: 'transparent'},
    chartArea: {'width': '100%', 'height': '80%'}
  };
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="container-user"></div>
```

note: the colors and series options map to each y-axis column in the data table.
so if you only have one y-axis column, as in the above example,
then you only have one series of data.
which is why you must use a `'style'` column role.

**EDIT**

you can use a data view to set the value of the style column,
after the data has been loaded.

this can be done by adding a calculated column,
that return the color for the last row / bar.

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([0, 1, {
  calc: function (dt, row) {
    // return color for last row
    if (row === (dt.getNumberOfRows() - 1)) {
      return '#1E90FF';
    }
    return null;
  },
  role: 'style',
  type: 'string'
}]);
```

then use the view to draw the chart,
see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x', 'y0'],
    ['17Jun', 1000],
    ['17Sep', 500],
    ['17Dec', 1000],
    ['18Mar', 750],
    ['18Jun', 1200],
    ['18Sep', 600,],
    ['18Dec', 1500,]
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1, {
    calc: function (dt, row) {
      // return color for last row
      if (row === (dt.getNumberOfRows() - 1)) {
        return '#1E90FF';
      }
      return null;
    },
    role: 'style',
    type: 'string'
  }]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('container-user'));
  var options = {
    colors: ['#B0C4DE'],
    orientation: 'horizontal',
    backgroundColor: {fill: 'transparent'},
    chartArea: {'width': '100%', 'height': '80%'}
  };
  chart.draw(view, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="container-user"></div>
```

Comment: data is dynamic so i can't add color to each column....I only want to change color of last bar..I tried many things but it doesn't work...If you able to set color on dynamic data that could be very helpful...

Comment: Buddy what you have done is correct, but still your code is not working on my side. Can you do it by another way...

Comment: will you please edit the question with the latest version of your code?

Comment: I made mistake that's why it was not working...but now i am facing new problem...I will update question with new problem.